# 307 Temporary Redirect Error Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, web-services

We are developing apps for both Android and iOS with the same Web service (JSON) from the same backend. As well, the same URL is used

However, while connecting to the web service, we received "307 Temporary Redirect" Error in Android but not in iOS.

We are using below connection Classes:

- Android: HttpURLConnection
- iOS: NSURLConnection

We want to ask:

1. The cause of this error?
2. Why it appears in only one platform "Android" and not the other "iOS"?
3. How this could be resolved both from the backend and fronted?

Thanks,

Comment: Consider comparing all the HTTP headers that you are sending to the server on both platforms. Also, please detail your networking approach on both platforms. That may help to point out the problem.

Comment: The question has been updated. I have mentioned that we are using the same URL. Also, the used connection classes for both platforms

Comment: Are there any concurrent requests?

Comment: Could you clarify your question ?

Comment: Are there any requests happening at the same time? Perhaps while your application is bootstrapping?

Comment: No. There is only one request at a time

Answer (score 1):

```
**307 Temporary Redirect: What It Is and How to Fix It- Android**
```

You can create an extra interceptor to handle 307:

```
private static class RedirectInterceptor implements Interceptor {@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    if (response.code() == 307) {
        request = request.newBuilder()
                .url(response.header("Location"))
                .build();
        response = chain.proceed(request);    }
    return response;
}
```

and add the RedirectInterceptor to your okHttpClient(okhttp2 for example)

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new RedirectInterceptor());
okHttpClient.setFollowRedirects(false);
```